# Php Image Transformation not Doing What I Expect It to Do

Tags: php, image, syntax, gd, rgb

The following block of php code is supposed to take [this image](http://quicksnaildesign.com/input.png) as input snd produce [this image](http://quicksnaildesign.com/output.png) as output (convert the black to yellow and the light-blue to black):

However, I'm getting [this image](http://quicksnaildesign.com/error.png) as output instead.

Can anyone see the problem with my code?

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng("./input.png");
$width = imagesx($im);
$height = imagesy($im);
$new = imagecreate($width, $height);
imagecopy($new, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
imagecolorset($new, imagecolorexact($new, 0, 0, 0), 255, 255, 0);

for($i = 0; $i < $width; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < $height; $j++) {
        $index = imagecolorat($new, $i, $j);
        $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($new, $index);
        if($rgb['red'] != 255 && $rgb['green'] != 255 && $rgb['blue'] != 0) {
            echo '(' . $i . ', ' . $j . ')' . 'color => (' . (255 - $rgb['blue']) . ', ' . (255 - $rgb['blue']) . ', 0)<br />';
            $color = imagecolorallocate($new, 255 - $rgb['blue'], 255 - $rgb['blue'], 0);
            imagesetpixel($new,  $i, $j, $color);
        }
        unset($index);
        unset($rgb);
    }
}
imagepng($new, 'tesst.png');
imagedestroy($im);
imagedestroy($new);
```

Comment: http://quicksnaildesign.com/error.png

Comment: something with execution time maybe. it works but it stops converting after 100 pixels in width or so

Comment: I am checking with that 'echo' to see the pixel (x,y) I reach in the for, and it seems I reach all of them and they are also valid (between 0 and 255). The problem seems to be with: $color = imagecolorallocate($new, 255 - $rgb['blue'], 255 - $rgb['blue'], 0);
            imagesetpixel($new,  $i, $j, $color);

Comment: For some reason it seems to work with: imagecolorset($new, imagecolorexact($new, $rgb['red'], $rgb['green'], $rgb['blue']), 255 - $rgb['blue'], 255 - $rgb['blue'], 0); 

Instead of imagesetpixel.

Maybe php bug?

Comment: I played with the code and got it to work by changing imagecreate to imagecreatetruecolor

Comment: Just tried with imagecreatetruecolor and the output seems wrong: http://quicksnaildesign.com/example.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the source of the issue here is that when using a palette based image, such as the one you have created by calling `imagecreate()`, it is possible to declare the same color at multiple indexes within the palette.

This means that, because you are calling `imagecolorallocate()` on every iteration, the palette eventually becomes full and `imagecolorallocate()` starts returning `false` (this can be seen if you `var_dump($color);` before the `imagesetpixel()` call). `false` evaluates to zero when cast to an integer - so when the palette fills up, all remaining pixels are effectively converted to the background color.

There are two things that you could do about this, the first and probably easiest is just to use a true-color image, which is just a simple case of changing `imagecreate($width, $height);` to `imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);`.

If you want to stick with the palette-based image (for example for reasons of output image data size - with an image containing so few colors, a palette-based image will be considerably smaller), you will need to cache the allocated colors manually so you can re-use them, something like this:

```
// ...

$colors = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) { // iterate x axis
    for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) { // iterate y axis
        // Get the color at this index
        $index = imagecolorat($new, $x, $y);

        // Only allocate a new color if not already done
        if (!isset($colors[$index])) {
            $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($new, $index);
            if ($rgb['red'] != 255 || $rgb['green'] != 255 || $rgb['blue'] != 0) {
                // If it's not the background color allocate a new color
                $r = $g = 255 - $rgb['blue'];
                $b = 0;

                $colors[$index] = imagecolorallocate($new, $r, $g, $b);
            } else {
                // Otherwise set the index to false, we can ignore it
                $colors[$index] = false;
            }
        }

        // If there's something to do, do it
        if ($colors[$index] !== false) {
            imagesetpixel($new, $x, $y, $colors[$index]);
        }
    }
}

// ...
```

You may also wish to track the colors in use in the image so you can "cleanse the palette" afterwards (i.e. deallocate any colors that are no longer in use in the image, which will further help with the data size reduction). Although arguably it would be better, in this case, to start with a clean palette and inspect the old image resource to get the pixel details, instead of copying the original to a new image resource.

Comment: You are my shining armored knight :)

Answer (score 0):

yes your

```
$color = imagecolorallocate($new, 255 - $rgb['blue'], 255 - $rgb['blue'], 0);
```

is messing everything up..

if you desire the same output... just paste the line outside for loop this will solve your problem if you want the specific image:

```
$color = imagecolorallocate($new, 35, 35, 0); //got from debugging
```

and it will get u the desired output.

Dins

Comment: There are more than two colors in the image, there is smoothing round the edges of the shapes ;-)

Comment: I agree.. I have not explored much of the gd so don't know much about the inner workings, your answer explain it well and makes more sense ..